# Login redirection leads to unrelated article

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, login, redirect

I am trying to set up a staff page using hidden menu items.

The login point is a public menu item, which should redirect to a menu item with registered access. Unfortunately a successful login redirects to the article (not menu item) associated with an unrelated login module.

Changing the login redirection selection does not impact where I am sent, and when I go directly to the URL i would like it to reach, I can see that it is set up properly.

you can test it at the links below using the login and password test1/54321

[roadstosuccess.org/staff](http://www.roadstosuccess.org/staff)

desired redirect would be

[roadstosuccess.org/staff/welcome](http://www.roadstosuccess.org/staff/welcome)

Comment: What version of Joomla, and are you using a 3rd party redirect component or the custom Joomla one? Clear cache, check SEO settings?

Comment: Joomla version 3.3.6, Joomla redirect component, and cache is cleared. which SEO settings could have an impact on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the welcome page, you can check what Url is included as a hidden parameter. It is encoded with Base64.

In your case, it has aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0yNjM=. You can decode it (http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) and get "index.php?Itemid=263"

If you need to define a return Url beyond the module parameters, you can just define a module override and fix the Url.

*You can find the original layout in modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php, and the return parameter in line 166.*

Ref: **Module Layout Overrides** https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you point me in the direction of how to define a module override in order to change the URL? everything i looked up seems to be about changing layout and template, and the appropriate folder isnt jumping out at me from the /modules folder on cpanel.

Comment: You can find the original layout in modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php, and the return parameter in line 166. Ref: Module Layout Overrides https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides